# How to do authorization fetch with GraphQL POST request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm trying to make a GraphQL request by using fetch method to get a schema.
On AWSAppSync in my settings I see the API URL and API ID, but I have no idea how to configure my fetch POST request properly to get the response with data I need.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
fetch('https://qnwb7jaoxdyky6egh4.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
Authorization: 'Basic bnwak7alhw52rlioy',  <----- this is API ID from AWS AppSync settings
'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      variables: {},
      query: `
      {
        __schema {
          types {
            kind
            name
            possibleTypes {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    }),
  })
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((result) => {
      debugger;  <--------- here I'm expecting to see the response data, but I see an error "UnauthorizedException"

      // here we're filtering out any type information unrelated to unions or interfaces
      const filteredData = result.data.__schema.types.filter(
        (type) => type.possibleTypes !== null,
      );
      
      result.data.__schema.types = filteredData;
      fs.writeFile('./fragmentTypes.json', JSON.stringify(result.data), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error writing fragmentTypes file', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Fragment types successfully extracted!');
        }
      });
    });
```

I'm using API URL and API ID from AWS AppSync settings.

I don't know why, but I get an error: "message: "Unable to parse JWT token."

Answer (score 1):

I have passed the API key in headers like this, in my case, I am calling APPSync Graphql endpoint which works with API key

```
headers: {
        "x-api-key": "XXXX-XXXXXXX", // API key here
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the right headers in your AppSync POST request. The required headers vary by
[authorization mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authz.html). API Key auth is the default "default authorization mode".  Check the AppSync console settings tab.

```js
// API_KEY
headers: {
  `x-api-key`:  "da2-the.api.key.from.the.appsync.console"
}

// AMAZON COGNITO_USER_POOLS
headers: {
  Authorization: "ey.jwt.token.a.really.really.long.string.you.get.from.cognito.after.you.login",
  host: 'qnwb7jaoxdyky6egh4.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' // the middle bits of the URL
}
```

Comment: I see that in my case the default authorization mode is "Amazon Cognito User Pool" but I can't find JWT token to use it for my purpose. Do I need to create it somehow or where I can find it?

Comment: Right, I should have said `API_KEY` is the "default _default authorization mode_".  Answer edited.

Comment: If you configure Appsync for Cognito auth, you exchange your UserPool username and password credentials for a JWT.
The [SDK InitiateAuthCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/initiateauthcommand.html) returns a token.  Amplify
has [frontend libraries](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js) and UI components to support user auth flows for React and other web apps.  Note: you can use Amplify's frontend tools without the backend "Amplify  CLI".