# TypeError: eader content ["Authorization"] in axios

Tags: typescript, axios, graphql, aws-appsync, mutation

I'm currently trying to implement graphql mutation execution in the backend (TypeScript).
Use the axios method.

The source code is below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErsVl.png)

When I tried it, I got the error "TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"].

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Please edit the post to add a code block [instead of the image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(token)`?  After you solve the type error, you will also need to [add the headers AppSync expects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70323228/1103511) to your `axios` call.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.